# Finding multiple subsets of lists or single superset of multiple lists

Tags: python

I have a list which contains 1 to n elements. The list object is :

```
[['Market F', 'Others', 'FR A', 'BR A', 'SBR A'], 
['Market J', 'Competitor A', 'FR Y', 'BR I', 'SBR AJ'], 
['Market L', 'Others', 'FR Q', 'BR A', 'SBR A'], 
['Market M', 'Others', 'FR G', 'BR B', 'SBR B'], 
['Market N', 'My Company', 'FR W', 'BR D', 'SBR H'], 
['Market TT', 'Others', 'FR Q', 'BR A', 'SBR A'], 
['Market U', 'Others', 'FR Q', 'BR A', 'SBR A'], 
['Market F', 'Others', 'FR A', 'BR A'], 
['Market J', 'Competitor A', 'FR Y', 'BR I'], 
['Market L', 'Others', 'FR Q', 'BR A'], 
['Market M', 'Others', 'FR G', 'BR B'], 
['Market TT', 'Others', 'FR Q', 'BR A'], 
['Market U', 'Others', 'FR Q', 'BR A'], 
['Market F', 'Others', 'FR A'], 
['Market J', 'Competitor A', 'FR Y'], 
['Market L', 'Others', 'FR Q'], 
['Market M', 'Others', 'FR G'], 
['Market TT', 'Others', 'FR Q'], 
['Market U', 'Others', 'FR Q'], 
['Market F', 'Others'], 
['Market J', 'Competitor A'], 
['Market J']]
```

For e.g.

- `['Market J']` is a subset of:
- `['Market J', 'Competitor A']` which is a subset of:
- `['Market J', 'Competitor A', 'FR Y']` which is again a subset of:
- `['Market J', 'Competitor A', 'FR Y', 'BR I']` and this is a subset of:
- `['Market J', 'Competitor A', 'FR Y', 'BR I', 'SBR AJ']`

In the reverse order, each is a superset of the latter.

What I would like to do is show that relation in the form of a dictionary like:

```
{"['Market J']": [
    ['Market J', 'Competitor A'],
    ['Market J', 'Competitor A', 'FR Y'],
    ['Market J', 'Competitor A', 'FR Y', 'BR I']
]}
```

(Where the keys are the elements of my list excluding keys which themselves would be contained in the value of another key e.g. `"['Market J']"` would be a key but `"['Market J', 'Competitor A']"` would not.)

or a better data structure if you could suggest. I would post a code-snippet but I can't think of an optimal way to do it.

Comment: Unravel your data into a tree structure. [`anytree`](https://pypi.org/project/anytree/) should have enough to get you started...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
l = [...]

# Dictionary keys must be immutable
l = [tuple(x) for x in l]

# Taking only proper subsets
d = {key: [match for match in l if set(key).issubset(match)  and not 
                                   set(match).issubset(key)] for key in l}

# Removing keys with no supersets
d = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if v}

# Removing keys which are supersets of other keys
d = {k:v for k, v in d.items() if k not in [item for sublist in d.values() 
                                                       for item in sublist]}
```

```
print(d)
>>>{('Market TT', 'Others', 'FR Q'): [('Market TT', 'Others', 'FR Q', 'BR A', 'SBR A'), ('Market TT', 'Others', 'FR Q', 'BR A')], 
    ('Market L', 'Others', 'FR Q'): [('Market L', 'Others', 'FR Q', 'BR A', 'SBR A'), ('Market L', 'Others', 'FR Q', 'BR A')], 
    ('Market M', 'Others', 'FR G'): [('Market M', 'Others', 'FR G', 'BR B', 'SBR B'), ('Market M', 'Others', 'FR G', 'BR B')], 
    ('Market U', 'Others', 'FR Q'): [('Market U', 'Others', 'FR Q', 'BR A', 'SBR A'), ('Market U', 'Others', 'FR Q', 'BR A')], 
    ('Market F', 'Others'): [('Market F', 'Others', 'FR A', 'BR A', 'SBR A'), ('Market F', 'Others', 'FR A', 'BR A'), ('Market F', 'Others', 'FR A')], 
    ('Market J',): [('Market J', 'Competitor A', 'FR Y', 'BR I', 'SBR AJ'), ('Market J', 'Competitor A', 'FR Y', 'BR I'), ('Market J', 'Competitor A', 'FR Y'), ('Market J', 'Competitor A')]}
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without using sets? Because when there is a duplicate value inside the tuples, this piece of code behaves differently, making duplicate relations.